# Passing in multiple data types in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, syntax

How do I pass in a Hash, String, Array and Symbol to a function in Ruby? I tried it this way:

```
func key: 'value', 'string', ['some', 'array'], :asymbol
```

This does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `{}` around the hash if there are other arguments that come after it.

```
# this will work
func({key: 'value'}, 'string', ['some', 'array'], :asymbol)
```

Because of this, it's very common to see hash types as the last argument in a method signature. Just update your method to accept the hash last.

```
# this will work, too
func 'string', ['some', 'array'], :asymbol, key: 'value'
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use brackets to pass additional params after a hash. They can only be implied for the last argument to a method.

```
func({key: 'value'}, 'string', ['some', 'array'], :asymbol)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is bad. Please use parenthesis and brackets:

```
func({key: "val"}, 'str', [1, 2], :sym)
```

Otherwise, the language is just seeing gibberish.

Comment: in my use-case the parenthesis and brackets are bad

Comment: @user738888: Because you have no {} or parenthesis.

Comment: @user738888: Why are they "bad"?

Comment: syntax noise, trying to avoid it

Comment: @user738888: This isn't syntax noise -- this is just necessary. Trying to get out of every little character is just bad practice. And Ruby's one of the best languages for that. Just look at C, and this will be nothing.

Comment: who said it was practice, i said in my particular use case the syntax noise is unfavourable

Comment: @user738888: Just remember, it only makes your code harder to read and understand.

Comment: i know. luckily nobody is meant to read it except the user who wrote it in my app.